# How to use Tensorflow keras Tokenization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`TensorFlow is a free and open-source software library for machine learning. It can be used across a range of tasks but has a particular focus on training and inference of deep neural networks. Tensorflow is a symbolic math library based on dataflow and differentiable programming.`

For example, splitting the above as if it were the text below, rather than dividing words by spaces.

`TensorFlow / is / a / free / and / open-source software library / for / machine learning./ It  / can be used / across / a range of / tasks / but / has / a particular / focus on / training / and / inference of deep neural networks/. Tensorflow / is / a / symbolic math library / based on / dataflow / and / differentiable programming.`

Comment: so you want to split by " / " instead of " " (space)?

Comment: For example, I'd like to split it into `open-source software library`, not `open`, `source`, `software`, `library` by space.

Comment: @stackTT You could use [tf.strings.regex_replace](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace) for replacing " " with " / ".
The keras' tokenizer allows to vectorize a text corpus, by turning each text into either a sequence of integers (each integer being the index of a token in a dictionary) or into a vector where the coefficient for each token could be binary, based on word count.